# Use variable in binding on Vega Lite

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega-lite, vega

I'm trying to create a custom Kibana visualization here, using Vega Lite. I have my datapull:

```
data: {
  url: {
    %context%: true
    %timefield%: dateStamp
    index: index_1
    body: {
      size: 10000
    }
}
```

I have a simple bind parameter in Vega Lite like so:

```
{
  name: displayBars
  value: 10
  bind: {
    input: range
    min: 3
    max: 40
    step: 1
  }
}
```

I'd like to change the `max` to a variable `hits.total`, like this:

```
{
  name: displayBars
  value: 10
  bind: {
    input: range
    min: 3
    max: hits.total
    step: 1
  }
}
```

Where `hits.total` represents the total documents returned by the kibana search. Is this possible?